# Use array and function in Component prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add array and function inside props but seems that I'm using wrong way

```
<Component
  property={{functionName, array}}
</Component>
```

```
const array = { 
  id: 1234,
  name: 'John Doe'
  address: 'Address'
}
```

I'm not sure if prop `property={{functionName, array}}` should be used in this way, because array now is inside object.

Comment: pass it as two different props, what is the use case ?? moreover, it is the children who want the props and handle both separately as two separate props entities. I believe what your doing is  completely wrong

Comment: what exactly do you want to do? why dont you use second property?

Comment: hmm, I need to use in the same prop because I'm just using component and I can't create another prop that do same function

Comment: post the code of `Component` in order to help you better

Answer (score 0):

The best options (but it is personal), will be

```
const myExampleFuction = ()=>{};
const myExampleArray = {a:1,b:2};
const myProps ={myExampleFunction,myExampleArray};

return <Component property={myProps} />;
```

Comment: is the same thing. I can't use array inside object.

Comment: Can you clarify? I don't undestand. In Component you will receive 2 props, 1 is myExampleArray and 1 is myExampleFunction

Comment: no, component has just one prop, in this prop I need to put a function and an array.

Comment: in this props, you need 2 different keys ? One per function and one per array? Or all together at the same level?

Comment: all together at the same level

Comment: So, the property need the keys id,name,address, functionName ? All together?

Comment: the property need one function that do something, and one array that has objects inside that.